# a python stack for a simple webapp with xmlrpc and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, xml-rpc

I'm looking for a nice python based framework that integrated well with xml-rpc and sqlalchemy.

I've investigated php based solutions already, and CodeIgniter + Doctrine has the features I need, but SQLAlchemy seems so much nicer than Doctrine, that I would prefer using it if I can get it integrated easily into an xmlrpc aware web framework.

Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

web.py is one of the simplest frameworks, that do not impose unreasonable restrictions on used components. If you need a tool that "integrates easily with X", then give it a try.

You can use this example of xmlrpc integration: http://webpy.org/tricks/xmlrpc
And this one, for sqlalchemy: http://webpy.org/cookbook/sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

How about Pylons? http://pylonsproject.org/